# Better performance of a service call than a library was not expected

Tags: c#, .net, model-view-controller, console-application, performance-testing

I was trying to figure out some performance values of two scenarios. I thought I was only going to declare the obvious at first. But when I got the results I got a little confused. And now I am looking for a justification for the case.

I have a library which makes couple of queries through a MongoDb database and Active Directory services, then returns the results to client, which are:

- GetUserType - to MongoDb - there is a collection which has username and type fields in its all documents. In the query I give the username and ask for the type field.
- LoginCheck - to Active Directory - given the username and the password from the client, I create a `PrincipalContext` object to access to AD server and call `ValidateCredentials` upon it.

This job is performing on an existing MVC application at the moment. And we are going to create a new desktop application and employ it with the same job.

We were curios about how different can these two scenarios perform? We thought that a direct call to a library without any http connection would perform better than a service request without an hesitation. But we still wondered how much difference is there, and if it was acceptable we are going to make it work through the rest MVC service - because of reasons :)

Hence we tested out the following architectures:

**Scenario 1:**

[image: Case 1]

**Scenario 2:**

[image: Case 2]

Basically, what I do for performance test is this:

**For scenario 1:**

```
for(var i = 0; i<10000; i++)
{
    new Class1().HeavyMethod();
}
```

**For scenario 2:**

```
// client side
for(var i = 0; i<10000; i++)
{
    using ( var client = new HttpClient() )
    {
        var values = new Dictionary<string, string>();
        var content = new FormUrlEncodedContent(values);
        var response = client.PostAsync("http://localhost:654/Home/HeavyLift", content).Result;
        var responseString = response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync().Result;
    }
}

// MVC rest service
public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public JsonResult HeavyLift()
    {
        return Json(new Class1().HeavyMethod(), JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
    }
}
```

**Common Class:**

```
public class Class1
{
    public string HeavyMethod ()
    {
        var userName = "asdfasdfasd";
        var password = "asdfasdfasdf";
        try
        {
            // this call is to MongoDB
            var userType = Personnel.GetPersonnelsType(userName).Result;  
            // this call is to Active Directory  
            var user = new ADUser(new Session 
            { 
                UserType = userType.Type, 
                UserName = userName, 
                Password = password 
            });

            return userType.Type + "-" + user.Auth();
        }
        catch ( Exception e )
        {
            return e.Message;
        }
    }
}
```

The results for 10000 consecutive calls are confusingly shocking:

> **Scenario 1:** 159181 ms
>
> **Scenario 2:** 13952 ms

`Scenario 1` starts off pretty quicly for the first few dosens of calls, then it starts to slow down.
`Scenario 2` though offers a constant response time through 10k calls.

What is actually happening here?

**Note:** I checked the memory and cpu usages of the server that this scenarios runs on(everything runs on the same server) but there is nothing interesting actually, they are behaving just the same in terms of memory and cpu resources.

Comment: Did you compile both in release configuration? because debug can make a huge performance impact

Comment: Is there any ORM used to query DB? Was thinking about ORM Session getting dirty if not used properly from ClassLibrary, while each Http request creates new ORM Session. But generally question is missing details, we cannot reproduce the issue, we have to guess.

Comment: Yes, I once learnt it in the hard way :) couple of years ago. They both are in release configuration.

Comment: I only use mongodb C# driver for the db queries. I don't think it is an ORM, or is it?

Comment: I know the question is an inreproduceble state right now, but it's not possible that I put all the reproducing codes here :/ Let me put at least the reproducing logic to the question.

Comment: and those calls from the console app are all synchronous? No async/await magic?

Comment: No mambo jambo, plain synchron calls.

Comment: Guessing here, but any chance of caching for the Service case?  Specifically is My Worker Library still being called 10000 times?

Comment: @3115 , I've added the code logic too, to reproduce the error.

Comment: @rene , I've added the code logic too, to reproduce the error.

Comment: @Chris O , I've added the code logic too, to reproduce the error.

Comment: Yes I did spam the comments :) sorry

Comment: I suspect in your situation 2 that you're seeing the IIS helping you out. But I think you need to try and simplify your investigations, because right now you have many factors involved, so try and do some static set amount work in HeavyMethod that you'll be pretty sure will always take x amount of time and not involved IO or Memory to help you focus on fewer parameters at the time. Also - you could try to hook up a performance profiler and investigate the call stacks for running time and number of hits.

Comment: Good starting and falling performance can point to GC problems. In java world You can read evangelism usually called "low latency", most of this ideas are good for C# too

Comment: éc, this is really shocked :D. Your test result looks suspicious to me. Maybe scenario 1 was tested in a deployment model in which Console App 1 remotely consumed MongoDB and DC while Console App 2 in scenario 2 did all stuff locally. I could only thing about that :))

Comment: @Allan S. Hansen , I actually did this test first with "DoNothing" version. Which run as expected, 0 milliseconds for Library Version and aroun 5-10 milliseconds for MVC Version. Then I changed to real stuff that I will do with these apps.

Comment: @Bob Dust , unfortunately both scenarios are tested in same environment, and actually in same application with different configurations to pick the code to execute.

Comment: @Jacek Cz , I will look into that "low latency" concept. Sounds like a good idea.

Comment: @TolgaEvcimen If you get a different result with a "DoNothing" version, then the culprit seems to be how HeavyMethod is used in the two scenarios. I'd attach a profiler to see how the code is called and how performance looks in the two versions to get line-by-line comparison numbers.

Comment: Are you sure the scenario 2 code is correct? It seems to be it should return after one iteration (due to the return in the using block)  but  maybe the PostAsync calls on your httpclient  get going anyway so that you get way more calls out.

Comment: @rene, Uhm, sorry that is a typo. Fixed it.